# Add data from one table to sheet as value

Tags: excel, vba

Have a problem with my Excel table.
I have a smart table on sheet "Order calculation" and I would like to move this data to sheet "Sales History"

code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateLogWorksheet()

    Dim historyWks As Worksheet
    Dim inputWks As Worksheet

    Dim nextRow As Long
    Dim oCol As Long

    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim myCopy As String
    Dim myCell As Range
    
    'cells to copy from Input sheet - some contain formulas
     myCopy = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Select

    Set inputWks = Worksheets("Order calculation")
    Set historyWks = Worksheets("Sales History")

    With historyWks
        nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    End With

   

    With historyWks
        With .Cells(nextRow, "A")
            .Value = Now
            .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
        End With
        
        
        With inputWks
        Set myRng = .Range(myCopy)

        If Application.CountA(myRng) <> myRng.Cells.Count Then
            MsgBox "Please fill in all the cells!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    
    
        .Cells(nextRow, "B").Value = Application.UserName
        oCol = 3
        For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
            historyWks.Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = myCell.Value
            oCol = oCol + 1
        Next myCell
    End With
    
    'clear input cells that contain constants
    With inputWks
      On Error Resume Next
         With .Range(myCopy).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
              .ClearContents
              Application.GoTo .Cells(1) ', Scroll:=True
         End With
      On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - please read [ask] - and then enhance your question. Otherwise we don't know what your problem is or how we could help you.

Comment: Please do not include links to your google drive in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to copy one sheet onto another, you can use the .Copy function of the Range object.

```
Sheets("Order calculation").Range("A1:AZ1000").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sales History").Range("A1")
```

You will just need to decide what part of the source sheet to copy (A1:AZ1000) and where you want this copied to on the destination sheet (A1).

Comment: This table is calculation and after final calculation i will need to copy it to next sheet  "sales history" so i will add it all the time

Comment: So you could add that "copy" line after you have finished your calculations. If you are using VBA to generate the table, simply include that copy line before the end of the subroutine.

If you are making changes manually (in Excel rather than VBA) then you could add an "change" event listener and call the "copy" function from there?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change

Comment: thx, could you please support with modificated code?

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range) 

    Sheets("Order calculation").Range("A1:AZ1000").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sales History").Range("A1")

End Sub

Comment: Thx, but this is not working as it have. I need to this table to add to Worksheets("Sales History") all the time after button press. 1 after one

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're hoping to achieve here. If you want to APPEND the new data to the "Sales History" sheet, then try getting the "last row" of the sheet, and using this as the "start row" for your destination. See https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-last-row/ for getting the last row (e.g. as intLastRow), and then change the destination for the copy function to:

Destination:=Sheets("Sales History").Range("A" & intLastRow)